# The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status

Tags: linux, git, ssh, vagrant

each time I do the vagrant up command I get the error

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

chown `id -u vagrant`:`id -g vagrant` /vagrant

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

chown: changing ownership of ‘/vagrant’: Not a directory
```

I can't find any solutions ( already tried to change the sudoers file but don't know exactly what to change)

Comment: vagrant up does provisioning by default. Is the error associated with the provisioning? if so then you will get a better error message if you vagrant ssh into the vm and then run your provisioning script.

Comment: The `/vagrant` directory is shared automatically during provisioning. The error, to me, suggests an issue with the provider and provision. Please post your `vagrantfile` and if possible any provisioning scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vagrant up error, changing ownership of /vagrant: not a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380799/vagrant-up-error-changing-ownership-of-vagrant-not-a-directory)

Answer (score 2):

> chown: changing ownership of ‘/vagrant’: Not a directory

This sounds like `/vagrant` is **Not a directory**, which probably it is a file, therefore remove the file and re-try again.

Or try to re-create your VM again, also double check your `Vagrantfile` if such file is not created.

To investigate the issue further, run the vagrant in the debug mode, e.g.

```
vagrant up --debug
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a version 0.21 for vagrant-vbguest helped me to fix mine

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vbguest --plugin-version 0.21
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to get a Vagrant 1.9.1-VirtualBox 5.1.10-Fedora 25 x64-Atomic host image running on my Windows 10 x64 Host.

I thought the Vagrant plugin vbguest didn't work well with the Atomic host type, as it mentioned during the provisioning.

Turns out the error still occurred for me, and I found this bug report: [Vagrant cannot create synced folder](https://pagure.io/atomic-wg/issue/181).

*dustymabe* seems to support the situation with a temporary workaround until the bug is fixed by using this line of code:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/tmp", "/vagrant", disabled: 'true'
```

*jorti*, the user that seems to be having the same issue as I, has used these lines of code both to workaround the bug, and set-up their own pathway to continue working with the same feature:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/provision", type: "rsync"
```

This issue was reported on Nov 25 2016 at 14:45:46, and was only commented on currently just up to 3 days after that time.

Answer (score 0):

This is no permission problem, but a simple error message, that the expected home directory "/vagrant" does not exist. It may be a file or just not existent.

Anyway this command has to be called by user root.

Just create that directory:

```
mkdir /vagrant
```

as user root.

Comment: While technically speaking this answer is correct, the `/vagrant` directory is created automatically by vagrant during provisioning. If it isn't created automatically, it is usually a sign that something more serious is wrong, and this answer is treating a symptom not the problem.