# Error trying to Homestead up after Vagrant update

Tags: laravel, vagrant, puppet, homestead, puphpet

I've been using Homestead in a Windows host for quite a while, running several projects (just one of them uses Laravel) at the same time without remarkable problems. But then I decided to try using another Vagrant environment with these projects. This decision has lead to problems trying to run Homestead again.

First, I created a custom environment from puphpet.com, pointing at the same folder location in the guest machine: *d:\www*, and, as said in their docs, ran *vagrant up* after extracting the downloaded zip. It asked me to upgrade Vagrant to version 1.8.x. So I did that downloading the latest Vagrant version and installing it in Windows.

Once installed, I get this message when doing homestead up:

> The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
>   Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> chown `id -u vagrant`:`id -g vagrant` /vagrant
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> chown: changing ownership of ÔÇÿ/vagrantÔÇÖ: Not a directory

Next if I try to enter one of my Homestead sites, I get a blank page with this text:

> **No input file specified.**

The **Homestead.yaml** file is the same as I had before:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:\Users\Luis\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:\Users\Luis\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\www
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
    - map:  D:\www\phpmyadmin
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
    - map:  D:\www\codeigniter
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/codeigniter
    - map:  D:\www\laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel
    - map:  D:\www\mysite
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/mysite
    - map:  D:\www\helpdesk
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/helpdesk

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
    - map: laravel.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/laravel/public
    - map: phpmyadmin.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/phpmyadmin
    - map: codeigniter.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/codeigniter
    - map: mysite.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/mysite
    - map: helpdesk.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/helpdesk/public

databases:
    - homestead
    - codeigniter
    - ceramicasmiramar
    - laravel
    - helpdesk

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

And this is the **config.yaml** file of the new environment I installed:

```
vagrantfile:
    target: local
    vm:
        provider:
            local:
                box: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
                box_url: puphpet/ubuntu1404-x64
                box_version: '0'
                chosen_virtualizer: virtualbox
                virtualizers:
                    virtualbox:
                        modifyvm:
                            natdnshostresolver1: false
                        showgui: 0
                    vmware:
                        numvcpus: 1
                    parallels:
                        use_linked_clone: 0
                        check_guest_tools: 0
                        update_guest_tools: 0
                machines:
                    vflm_owhi4bjucjib:
                        id: Vagrant2
                        hostname: vagrant2.puphpet
                        network:
                            private_network: 192.168.56.101
                            forwarded_port:
                                vflmnfp_wei9ytye6ol7:
                                    host: '5444'
                                    guest: '18'
                        memory: '512'
                        cpus: '1'
        provision:
            puppet:
                manifests_path: puphpet/puppet/manifests
                module_path: puphpet/puppet/modules
                options:
                    - '--verbose'
                    - '--hiera_config /vagrant/puphpet/puppet/hiera.yaml'
        synced_folder:
            vflsf_z9dj2qmap2mz:
                source: 'd:\www'
                target: /var/www
                sync_type: default
                smb:
                    smb_host: ''
                    smb_username: ''
                    smb_password: ''
                    mount_options:
                        dir_mode: '0775'
                        file_mode: '0664'
                rsync:
                    args:
                        - '--verbose'
                        - '--archive'
                        - '-z'
                    exclude:
                        - .vagrant/
                        - .git/
                    auto: 'true'
                owner: www-data
                group: www-data
        usable_port_range:
            start: 10200
            stop: 10500
        post_up_message: ''
    ssh:
        host: 'false'
        port: 'false'
        private_key_path: 'false'
        username: vagrant
        guest_port: 'false'
        keep_alive: '1'
        forward_agent: 'false'
        forward_x11: 'false'
        shell: 'bash -l'
        insert_key: 'false'
    vagrant:
        host: detect
    proxy:
        http: ''
        https: ''
        ftp: ''
        no_proxy: ''
server:
    install: '1'
    packages:
        - vim
        - composer
        - git
users_groups:
    install: '1'
    groups: {  }
    users: {  }
locale:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_locale: es_ES.UTF-8
        locales:
            - en_GB.UTF-8
            - en_US.UTF-8
        timezone: Europe/Madrid
firewall:
    install: '1'
    rules: {  }
cron:
    install: '1'
    jobs: {  }
nginx:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        default_vhost: 1
        proxy_buffer_size: 128k
        proxy_buffers: '4 256k'
        proxy_connect_timeout: 600s
        proxy_send_timeout: 600s
        proxy_read_timeout: 600s
        names_hash_bucket_size: 128
    upstreams: {  }
    vhosts:
        nxv_oi2pxhv8su8t:
            server_name: nginx.dev
            server_aliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
                - www.nginx.dev
            www_root: /var/www/nginx
            listen_port: '80'
            index_files:
                - index.html
                - index.htm
                - index.php
            client_max_body_size: 1m
            ssl: '1'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_port: '443'
            ssl_protocols: ''
            ssl_ciphers: ''
            rewrite_to_https: '1'
            spdy: '1'
            locations:
                nxvl_3fqbmcj47hvf:
                    location: /
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: ''
                    fastcgi_index: ''
                    fastcgi_split_path: ''
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
                nxvl_htslqsfqqunm:
                    location: '~ \.php$'
                    try_files:
                        - $uri
                        - $uri/
                        - /index.php$is_args$args
                    fastcgi: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                    fastcgi_index: index.php
                    fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
                    fast_cgi_params_extra:
                        - 'SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename'
                        - 'APP_ENV dev'
                    set:
                        - '$path_info $fastcgi_path_info'
                    proxy: ''
                    proxy_redirect: ''
    proxies: {  }
apache:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.4
        user: www-data
        group: www-data
        default_vhost: true
        manage_user: false
        manage_group: false
        sendfile: 0
    modules:
        - proxy_fcgi
        - rewrite
    vhosts:
        av_hyccqwe7iecr:
            servername: awesome.dev
            serveraliases:
                - www.awesome.dev
            docroot: /var/www/awesome
            port: '80'
            setenv:
                - 'APP_ENV dev'
            setenvif:
                - 'Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1'
            custom_fragment: ''
            ssl: '0'
            ssl_cert: ''
            ssl_key: ''
            ssl_chain: ''
            ssl_certs_dir: ''
            ssl_protocol: ''
            ssl_cipher: ''
            directories:
                avd_8x23jhnbgquk:
                    path: /var/www/awesome
                    options:
                        - Indexes
                        - FollowSymlinks
                        - MultiViews
                    allow_override:
                        - All
                    require:
                        - 'all granted'
                    custom_fragment: ''
                    files_match:
                        avdfm_vmmh0bjsaqhg:
                            path: \.php$
                            sethandler: 'proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000'
                            custom_fragment: ''
                            provider: filesmatch
                    provider: directory
letsencrypt:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        email: luis@luis.local
    domains: {  }
php:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '70'
    modules:
        php:
            - cli
            - intl
            - curl
            - memcached
            - mysql
            - mysqlnd
            - imap
        pear: {  }
        pecl: {  }
    ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        session.save_path: /var/lib/php/session
        date.timezone: UTC
    fpm_ini:
        error_log: /var/log/php-fpm.log
    fpm_pools:
        phpfp_vujhdkscen9a:
            ini:
                prefix: www
                listen: '127.0.0.1:9000'
                security.limit_extensions: .php
                user: www-user
                group: www-data
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
xdebug:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        xdebug.default_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_autostart: '0'
        xdebug.remote_connect_back: '1'
        xdebug.remote_enable: '1'
        xdebug.remote_handler: dbgp
        xdebug.remote_port: '9000'
blackfire:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        server_id: ''
        server_token: ''
        agent:
            http_proxy: ''
            https_proxy: ''
            log_file: stderr
            log_level: '1'
        php:
            agent_timeout: '0.25'
            log_file: ''
            log_level: '1'
xhprof:
    install: '0'
wpcli:
    install: '0'
    version: v0.21.1
drush:
    install: '0'
    version: 8.0.5
ruby:
    install: '1'
    versions:
        rv_2odx4yt5qrex:
            default: '1'
            bundler: '1'
            version: 1.9.3
            gems:
                - deep_merge
                - activesupport
                - vine
python:
    install: '1'
    packages: {  }
    versions: {  }
nodejs:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5'
    npm_packages: {  }
hhvm:
    install: '0'
    nightly: 0
    composer: '1'
    composer_home: ''
    settings: {  }
    server_ini:
        hhvm.server.host: 127.0.0.1
        hhvm.server.port: '9000'
        hhvm.log.use_log_file: '1'
        hhvm.log.file: /var/log/hhvm/error.log
    php_ini:
        display_errors: 'On'
        error_reporting: '-1'
        date.timezone: UTC
mariadb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: '10.1'
        root_password: '123'
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mariadbnu_kv8yudo3faat:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mariadbnd_d9sigtide5ol:
            name: dbname
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mariadbng_1ksysq92bh2p:
            user: dbuser
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
mysql:
    install: '1'
    settings:
        version: '5.6'
        root_password: mypassword
        override_options: {  }
    adminer: 0
    users:
        mysqlnu_qrdghfnjhslr:
            name: dbuser
            password: '123'
    databases:
        mysqlnd_8ltm71pgi42q:
            name: ''
            sql: ''
    grants:
        mysqlng_i9wsnaqkcck2:
            user: luis
            table: '*.*'
            privileges:
                - ALL
postgresql:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        global:
            encoding: UTF8
            version: '9.4'
        server:
            postgres_password: '123'
    databases: {  }
    users: {  }
    grants: {  }
    adminer: 0
mongodb:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        bind_ip: 127.0.0.1
        port: '27017'
    globals:
        version: 2.6.0
    databases: {  }
redis:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '6379'
sqlite:
    install: '0'
    adminer: 0
    databases: {  }
mailhog:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        smtp_ip: 0.0.0.0
        smtp_port: 1025
        http_ip: 0.0.0.0
        http_port: '8025'
        path: /usr/local/bin/mailhog
beanstalkd:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        listenaddress: 0.0.0.0
        listenport: '11300'
        maxjobsize: '65535'
        maxconnections: '1024'
        binlogdir: /var/lib/beanstalkd/binlog
        binlogfsync: null
        binlogsize: '10485760'
    beanstalk_console: 0
rabbitmq:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        port: '5672'
    users: {  }
    vhosts: {  }
    plugins: {  }
elastic_search:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 2.3.1
        java_install: true
    instances:
        esi_imx85v224tyv:
            name: es-01
solr:
    install: '0'
    settings:
        version: 4.10.2
        port: '8984'
```

Any ideas what do to fix it? Or at least how to roll it back to using only Homestead?

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally found the solution here:

[Vagrant up error, changing ownership of /vagrant: not a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380799/vagrant-up-error-changing-ownership-)[of-vagrant-not-a-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380799/vagrant-up-error-changing-ownership-of-vagrant-not-a-directory)

It was fixed by uninstalling Virtual Box 5 and installing VB 4.3